# How do I add an attribute to a link inside a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add an attribute to a link inside a textarea?

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="text"><a href="/" id="link">Click here</a></textarea>

<a href="#" id="add_attr">Add attribute</a>
<a href="#" id="remove_attr">Remove attribute</a>
```

**JavaScript, JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#add_attr').click(function()
    {
        var value = $('#text').val();

        //add attribute `class="name"` to the link inside the textarea
        return false;
    });

    $('#remove_attr').click(function()
    {
        var value = $('#text').val();

        //remove attribute `class="name"` from the link inside the textarea
        return false;
    });
 });
```

Comment: Links in a `textarea` are not part of the DOM. They are just text. http://jsfiddle.net/9pT7a/

Comment: That's why I was surprised by the answers below. But can't I just grab the text and then I dunno ..somehow add those attributes to the text?

Comment: basically get the textarea value and do some search/replace.

Comment: So you just downvote them all?

Comment: You can parse and replace the contents of the textarea. But I think this would require the use of a regex, and [parsing HTML with a regex is not a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: @Phil: Answers that are wrong should be downvoted. That's how the site works.

Comment: @Phil: and btw, I didn't downvote them ;) but I guess I agree with @George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('body').append('<div style="display: none;" id="hCreator">' + $('#text').val() + '</div>');
$('#hCreator a').attr('senad', 'senad');
$('#text').val($('#hCreator').html());
$('#hCreator').remove();
```

Comment: Note that will break if the value contains an unmatched `</div>`, and may change other bits of the text too, depending on the browser and the specific text (e.g. it might normalize tag soup, change entity references to literal characters or vice versa, or the like).

Comment: This is the only answer that addresses the fact that he's modifying the *contents of a `textarea`*, not the DOM.

Comment: This is just a technique, not a full solution.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#add_attr').click(function()
    {
        var value = '<div>' + $('#text').val() + '</div>';
        _value = $(value);
        _value.find('a').addClass('name');
        _value = _value.contents();
        $('#text').val($('<div>').append(_value.clone()).remove().html());
        return false;
    });

    $('#remove_attr').click(function()
    {
        var value = '<div>' + $('#text').val() + '</div>';
        _value = $(value);
        _value.find('a').removeClass('name');
        _value = _value.contents();
        $('#text').val($('<div>').append(_value.clone()).remove().html());
        return false;
    });
 });
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qWG7M/2/

Comment: That adds the class to every "top-level" tag in the text, not just the one link.

Comment: Updated before I saw your comment :)

Answer (score -1):

`$('textarea#text a#add_attr').addClass('name');`

Answer (score -1):

$("#text a").attr("yourattr","Val");